# what is a portable way in Ruby to check where STDIN will block if you attempt to read from it?

Tags: ruby, stdin

I would like to find out if there is a portable way to check in a Ruby script whether it will block if it attempts to read from STDIN. The following is an approach that works for Unix (and Cygwin) but not native Win32. (It is based on a Perl approach I learned long ago.)

---

$ cat read-stdin.rb

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
# test of reading from STDIN

require 'fcntl'

# Trace info on input objects
$stdout.sync=TRUE if $DEBUG         # make sure standard output and error synchronized
$stderr.print "ARGV=#{ARGV}\n" if $DEBUG
$stderr.print "ARGF=#{ARGF}\n" if $DEBUG

# See if input available, showing usage statement if not
blocking_stdin = FALSE
if (defined? Fcntl::F_GETFL) then
  $stderr.print "F_GETFL=#{Fcntl::F_GETFL} O_RDWR=#{Fcntl::O_RDWR}\n" if $DEBUG
  flags = STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL, 0) 
  $stderr.print "flags=#{flags}\n" if $DEBUG
  blocking_stdin = TRUE if ((flags & Fcntl::O_RDWR) == Fcntl::O_RDWR)
  $stderr.print "blocking_stdin=#{blocking_stdin}\n" if $DEBUG
end
if (blocking_stdin && (ARGV.length == 0)) then
  $stderr.print "usage: #{$0} [-]\n"
  Process.exit
end

# Read input and output it
$stderr.print "Input:\n" if $DEBUG
input_text = ARGF.read()
$stderr.print "Output:\n" if $DEBUG
print "#{input_text}\n"
```

Here is the interaction without debugging:

```
$ grep -v DEBUG read-stdin.rb >| /tmp/simple-read-stdin.rb

$ echo hey | ruby /tmp/simple-read-stdin.rb
hey

$ ruby /tmp/simple-read-stdin.rb
usage: /tmp/simple-read-stdin.rb [-]
```

Here is the interaction with debugging:

```
$ echo hey | ruby -d read-stdin.rb
ARGV=
ARGF=ARGF
F_GETFL=3 O_RDWR=2
flags=65536
blocking_stdin=false
Input:
Output:
hey

$ ruby -d read-stdin.rb
ARGV=
ARGF=ARGF
F_GETFL=3 O_RDWR=2
flags=98306
blocking_stdin=true
usage: read-stdin.rb [-]
```

Comment: A very portable way would be to spawn a thread that reads from STDIN (blocking) and writes the data to some kind of buffer, for another thread to use.

Comment: Ruby does have a portable layer over the UNIX `select`.

Comment: The portable `select` layer also works on Win32.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is universally portable and I also don't know if it is considered a good idea (blocking isn't such a bad concept) but there is a [non-blocking read method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) in IO. You can use it like this:

```
chunk = nil

begin
  chunk = STDIN.read_nonblock(4096)
rescue Errno::EAGAIN
  # Handle the case if it would block
  chunk = 'nothing there...'
end
```

Though, I think it's quite disappointing it doesn't work without specifying a buffer size like IO#read does it, but working around this by using a loop should be quite easy.

Comment: ARGF also has a [read_nonblock](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/ARGF.html#method-i-read_nonblock) method now